# Issue with countdown

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown timer on my web page. But I can't make it to work properly.

I have an end date - it's March 01, 2017.
And I have a current date:

```
var now = Date.now()
```

This is my whole code for this javascript:

```
CountDownTimer(1488326400000, 'clockdiv');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function showRemaining() {

        if (!Date.now) {
            Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
        }
       // var now = new Date();
        var now = Date.now()
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }

        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + days).slice(-2);
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);

        // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        // document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

The script showing me 26 days until the end date. It's not correct.
What is the mistake?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where specifically do the values differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cutting off the days to 2 characters:

```
daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + days).slice(-2);
```

Just do:

```
daysSpan.innerHTML = days;
```